# .htaccess rules with a subdomain and two domains

Tags: regex, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a domain `domain.com` that I use as my primary domain. I also own a second domain `domain2.com` that I have automatically go to `domain.com`

This is done with .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want to set up a subdomain `sub.domain.com` but with that current .htaccess, visiting sub.domain.com sends me to www.domain.com/sub

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263170/htaccess-to-require-www-for-domain-but-allow-subdomain-if-existing-with-no-hard) question, which solves this problem, but negates my first issue of `domain2.com` pointing to `domain.com`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I'm looking for a way to combine the two rules:

`www.domain.com` => www.domain.com
`domain.com` => www.domain.com
`domain2.com` => www.domain.com
`sub.domain.com` => sub.domain.com

Comment: I've added a bounty to this question. The answer provided by Gumbo is close, but doesn't quite satisfy the entirety of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([^.]+\.)example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Should solve your problem :D

Comment: This is the one that works, however, I can't seem to accept the answer. Sorry Mez.

Comment: Weird... Wonder who the bounty went to if you cant accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to tighten up your RewriteConds so that they only matched the specific hostnames you wanted to match and change, like ‘^domain\.com$’ and ‘^(www\.)?domain2\.com$’. At the moment they will both match pretty much anything, so they'll interfere.

But do you have to do this in .htaccess? It's much cleaner to do with a simple Redirect in your main site config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ...your real config...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    ServerAlias domain2.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    ServerAlias sub.domain.com
    Redirect permanent http://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

which also gets the nasty deployment-specific stuff out of your application's web root.

(I couldn't work out whether you actually wanted that the subdomain went to a different folder; if you do, remove the sub.domain.com line above and put it into its own VirtualHost:)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    Redirect permanent http://domain.com/sub/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with virutal host stuff or where to do any of this. I certainly don't HAVE to do this in .htaccess, but it's the only place I know how to (and I'm not even very good with that!)

Comment: I think he means, do you have access to httpd.conf?

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([^.]+\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This is very close to working. Out of the 4 cases listed at the bottom of the question, all work but the second one. If I just go to `domain.com` it doesn't add the www (which I would like it to do).

Answer (score 1):

Would this simply work :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```