# .htaccess root domain require www and sub domain not require www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, web

i want set the domain like below:

example.com -> www.example.com

example.com/page -> www.example.com/page

www.example.com -> does not redirect

www.example.com/page -> does not redirect

---

subdomain.example.com -> does not redirect

subdomain.example.com/page -> does not redirect

www.subdomain.example.com -> subdomain.example.com

www.subdomain.example.com/page -> subdomain.example.com/page

---

**http and https also should work.**

I get the code from [.htaccess to require WWW for domain, but allow subdomain if existing with no hard coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263170/htaccess-to-require-www-for-domain-but-allow-subdomain-if-existing-with-no-har)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

it can work very well for all, but except below:

www.subdomain.example.com -> www.subdomain.example.com

www.subdomain.example.com/page -> www.subdomain.example.com/page

the subdomain should **not** have 'www.' prefix but it still with 'www.' prefix.

thanks for tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after the rules you have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

I haven't tested it out, but I'm pretty sure my theory's solid on it. At least assuming the HTTPS part from your example works.

Comment: Now i paste this code at my .htaccess file:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$`
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|`
`RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`
 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+)$`
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|`
`RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

**for subdomain part is still get little problem:**

www.subdomain.domain.com -> subdomain.domain.com (done),
**www.subdomain.domain.com/page -> page/ (problem)**

Comment: Changed my answer. Requires two rewrite rules since I missed something in the htaccess docs.